# Running a command on each id in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, xargs

I have a text file with a list of id's like below and I need to run the below command on each of these ids,is there an easier way to do in awk?

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- file.txt
```

file.txt contains below:

```
297003
297002
297001
...
```

Following commands should be run as long as an id exists in file.text

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297003
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297002
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297001
.....
```

Comment: Run it "on" them how? Should each id be added to the end of the command line, or should one of the numbers in the command line be replaced?

Comment: Why do you want to use Awk for this? Shell script would seem the natural choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk isn't the tool I would jump for here. I suggest `xargs`:

```
xargs -I% -n1 < file ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- %
```

The `%` character is the replace string as set with the `-I` option however as the replacement is at the end of the command in this case it does not need to be explicitly stated as `xargs` simply appends to the end by default:

```
xargs -n1 < file ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 --
```

A tip is to use the `echo` command to see the output before you actually run it:

```
# -------------- notice we run echo not ssh to see the output before we rut it 
xargs -n1 < file echo ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297003
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297002
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297001
```

Without the `-n1` option `xargs` will passes all the values which may or may not be useful for this particular situation dependent on the usage of `gerrit`:

```
xargs < file echo ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- 297003 297002 297001
```

Comment: @sudo_O - Updated the question..port number is always constant..the "--" option changes for every id in file.txt

Comment: @user2125827 that makes much sense haha. I have updated my answer, the `%` is simply replace by each number in `file` so the `%` is just moved to the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while read sshid
do
  ssh -p $sshid ...
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while loop to carry out the operation on each value and set the values for `$i` as the output of a `read` of the file containing the list of values.

```
while read i
do
     ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- $i
done < filename
```

And as sudo_O stated, you can use an `echo` command to check the commands generated prior to trying to run the actual code.

```
while read i
do
     echo "ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit review --code-review 2 -- $i" 
done < filename
```

Comment: The proper way to code that is `while read i; do ... done <file.txt`

Comment: What is the advantage to using `while read i` rather than `for i in $( cat filename )`?

Comment: I've been made aware of my own bad habits. Thanks for the tips.